# Node server with PM2 closes with SIGTERM timeout : 1600

Tags: node.js, angular, pm2

I am running an Angular SSR app with PHP laravel backend for a website.
I have setup a node server, and managing it using PM2, spawning it using environment config as follows:

```js
 module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'FFBLive',
    script: 'local.js',
     // instances: "max",
    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
    args: 'one two',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: false, //was true before but tried turning it off to see if it helps
    watch_delay: 1000,
    ignore_watch : ["system202005","system202005/*"],
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],
```

The app spawns just fine, and runs properly for a while, and then after a while I get a 503 service unavailable on the website, and when I look in the server, the PM2 daemon is dead..when I try to see the logs, I get -

```html
pm2 logs
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home2/bfo/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/home2/bfo/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Time                 : Sat May 30 2020 21:23:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 3.5.1
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 10.20.1
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home2/bfo/.pm2
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home2/bfo/.pm2/pm2.pid
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home2/bfo/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home2/bfo/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Application log path : /home2/bfo/.pm2/logs
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home2/bfo/.pm2/dump.pm2
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
PM2        | 2020-05-30T21:23:24: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
```

The output log file contains -

```
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
{ catSlug: 'all', searchStr: 'Um9odQ' }
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
Listening on: http://localhost:9700
```

The error log does contain some exceptions, mostly related to my angular app not finding routes for the laravel index.php file - e.g.

```
    ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.php'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.php'
    at ApplyRedirects.module.exports.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (/home2/bfo/public_html/dist/server.js:165170:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (/home2/bfo/public_html/dist/server.js:165151:29)
```

And some cases where exceptions on the Laravel API (E.g. one vendor dependency was not properly imported in a controller) -

```
Class 'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider' not found
Class 'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider' not found
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Class 'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider' not found
    at resolvePromise (/home2/bfo/public_html/dist/server.js:123429:31)
```

But my questions are -
a) Can these exceptions cause a sigterm and cause the PM2 daemon to stop totally ? I didn't think so, but could be wrong.
b) I first thought that the watcher was watching too many files, as initially it was watching the PHP REST API files also which was in a subfolder, but then I added it to ignore watch list, and then simply turned watching off to see if that helps.
c) I am also wondering if resource allocation (e.g. memory) would cause this, but in that case it would just restart instead of dying.

I am not very familiar with PM2, and this is more of an experiment to get angular SSR to working properly off of a node server using PM2, so I might be doing something wrong in setting it up.

I tried googling for possible answers, but the results [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2396) and [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2013) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896215/pm2-daemon-dies-after-a-few-hours) were not really helpful.
Would be glad to have a few pointers to how to set this up properly for a stable production mode.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm running PM2 for a couple of years, an it works as expected in production environments. I will need a bit of context on you `local.js` file contents to see what you are doing. Related to your questions: (a) Yes, some exceptions triggers sigterms but you `autorestart: true` so, I do not see a problem here. (b) As I do not know what are you doing on your initiator JS, I cannot tell. (c) Yes, but thats why `max_memory_restart` stands for. Maybe, and like one post you cite, if you are using an external hosting, the manager cut off your service.

Comment: I just noticed something, I was running the pm2 process as a normal user account and it was having this constant refresh issue. Now I spawned the process as root, and it has been over 24 hours, with no restart.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by running the below commands.

```
npm uninstall -g pm2
npm install -g pm2@3.2.2
```